# Does mongodb-stitch support push notification for ionic?

Tags: push-notification, ionic3, mongodb-stitch

I am following this tutorial in mongodb stitch. https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/tutorials/push-notifications/

However it looks like this one is for android app only. I am developing an ionic app using mongodb stitch. Do you think mongodb stitch supports push notification for my ionic 3 app?

Answer (score 0):

Following your link reveals that MongoDB cloud services actually do not provide a complete standalone solution for push notifications. They suggest to setup Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) for this and you can configure stitch to trigger a push notification via FCM. You would need to setup firebase (free tier) for that and stitch separately. I do not know if that scales well and is at the time of my answer a big downside of MongoDB services.

Yeah, they just provide an example via Android, but I think using it on client side is very straight forward. The most part is configuring the backends.

I hope that helps.